# PowerShell command to create a SP User permission report

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to PowerShell. What's the best command to run to get a list of user permissions on a SP Online site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below PowerShell Script:

```
#SPO-specific cmdlets require sharepoint-online module

Install-Module -NameMicrosoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell

$ServiceURL ="https://enterprise-admin.sharepoint.com"

$URL = "https://enterprise.sharepoint.com"

$Path = "C:\Temp\GroupsReport.csv"

$Cred =  Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online

Connect-SPOService -url$ServiceURL -Credential$Cred

#Generating Report

$GroupsData = @()

#get sharepoint online groups powershell

$SiteGroups =Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site$URL

ForEach($Group in $SiteGroups) {

    $GroupsData +=New-Object PSObject-Property @{

        'Group Name' =$Group.Title

        'Permissions' =$Group.Roles -join ","

        'Users' =  $Group.Users -join ","

    }

}

#Export the data to CSV

$GroupsData |Export-Csv $Path-NoTypeInformation
```

**Output - Example**:

[image: Get SharePoint Online User Permission Report]

Reference:

[How to Get a SharePoint Online Permissions Report with PowerShell or Netwrix Auditor](https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_get_sharepoint_online_permissions.html)

**Prerequisites to execute the above script:**

- Need to install the SharePoint Online PowerShell module, the below command can be used to do so:

  Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell

Refer to this MSDN Article: [Get started with SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps)

**How to pass credential in the  Connect-SPOService?**

We can use any of the below formats:

```
$username = "admin@contoso.sharepoint.com"
$password = "password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred
```

or

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com
```

or

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
```

Source MSDN Article:

[Connect-SPOService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/connect-sposervice?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thanks, when I run the Connect cmd I get:  is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file...

Comment: also in what format would I need to add the credentials in that line?

Comment: Answer updated - please check the updated answer - for the connection you can use the below code: $username = "admin@contoso.sharepoint.com"
$password = "password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred